# Pads acting as heat sink for LED design

Tags: led, pcb-design, altium, solder-mask, solder-paste

I am using traces much wider than the LED footprint to dissipate heat. What design guidelines should I follow when making design like this.

- Should I add solder mask expansion between anode and cathode pads for correct placement of the LEDs?. I think there is no need for it on the other sides because even if the solder mask in misplaced little bit, the copper pad will still be complete. but The solder paste will be insufficient at the same time.
- what is the best practices to follow in this kind of designs? should I leave solder mask expansion and solder paste expansion equal on all sides?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "solder mask extension".  I usually put holes in the solder mask to match the pads that would be there if I weren't using thermal pads.  E.g. a SO-8 FET would have eight holes in the solder mask, even if it only has three connections.

Comment: I meant solder mask expansion pcb rule that increases the solder mask a little bit to to make room for solder mask misalignment during fabrication to avoid copper pads being covered. The question is How can I set this rules for this sort of designs.

Comment: Unless you're making 10,000 at a pop, I think it'll be somewhere between doesn't matter, and expanding the solder mask a bit will help slightly.  Regardless, the solder mask won't melt during reflow, and the chip will be pulled to center in the "pads" defined by the windows in the mask.

Comment: I'd strongly consider adding some thermal vias so that both sides of the board can help dissipate heat.

Comment: Actually the board is single layer. so we need a work around.